# How to set a background image of an html file using a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I apologize for the dumb question, I am very new to HTML/CSS and I find getting specific answers very confusing at times. I'm trying my best.

I wanted to upload a background image, and I was wondering how to do so using a div. I wanted to use a div because I don't know how to change the opacity of the background image without changing the opacity of the entire html document, so i figured using a div would allow me to do that. However, I'm not really sure how to use a div in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.divimg {
    background-image: url(../images/image.png); /* Your image */
}
</style>
```

Body:

```
<div class="divimg">
    <!-- Anything you want -->
</div>
```

You can change the background image with jquery too:

```
$('.divimg').css("background-image", "url(../images/image.png)");
```

Comment: I insert that all in the body? I can just move the .divimg to an external CSS file, right? I'm confused because I tried that before,but I don't know how that affects the rest of my html.

Comment: The style is in the head of the html or in a external css file. The style only affects the object in the html, in this case only affect the `divimg`.

Comment: when you have given divimg as class then how will you able to access using #.

Comment: Right Suchit Kumar, I changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.bgimg {
    background-image: url(../images/divbg.png);  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
}
</style>

...

<div class="bgimg">
    div with background
</div>
```

OR you can write `.bgimg` in external css file

Comment: where does the div go? within the <head> </head> tags or within the body? sorry for dumb question, its such a simple problem i know.

Comment: No..div goes to `<body div="name">` because you have to give backgrounf image to whole html file..right??

Comment: uh...nevermind. i dont know what <body div="name"> is, i thought a separate div would be created within the body then. thanks for trying to help though, im just too confused.